# Get fields comments instead of names when viewing object by "Identify feature" instrument

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

I have a point layer with column NAMES like: Object_ID, Type, Link, Area an so on. Each column title has a COMMENT, like: Object identification number, Type of organization, site URL, Floor area in square meters... When I click on the point with Identify feature instrument I get a list of it's NAMES - VALUES pairs. Is there a way to replace NAMES with COMMENTS for this instrument in order to see COMMENT-VALUES pairs? May be some other instruments exists to get such kind of data for each feature while viewing the map?
Looks like I want something strange, colleagues, nevertheless... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Attributes Form* tab of the layer's properties you can assign an *alias* to each of the **column names**. If you copy each **comment** in the *alias* of your **column name**, the *alias* will be shown in the form (when you click with Identify feature instrument) and in the table. With no alias, the default column name will be shown.

[more info on aliases and field properties](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=alias#fields-properties)

Comment: Wondeful! Thank you very much, @LeoC! I'm starting to think that in QGIS nearly nothing is impossible!